# Sources for letters written during the Boer Wars?

Tags: war, 19th-century, british-empire, africa, boer-war

For a project at my school I need to make a 'letter home' of a Canadian soldier that participated in the Second Boer War. I need to draw from primary sources and I'm not having luck finding any. Does anyone know where to find letters written by soldiers in the Second Boer War. (I can find stuff on the life of soldiers in the war no problem, but actual letters are kind of hard).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [one site](http://www.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~nslssgs/boer.htm) that has a few.  I hope you'll be using these as inspiration to write your own letter, not just copying them.  Good luck!